# Disable URL parameter from submit button in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, url-parameters

Clicking the button passes `button=` in the URL:

```
# example.html.haml
= form_for @contact, html: { method: :get }
  = f.text_field :phone
  = f.button "Call Me!"
```

How do I prevent Rails from passing along the extra URL parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `name: nil` to the button:

```
= form_for @contact, html: { method: :get }
  = f.text_field :phone
  = f.button "Call Me!", name: nil
```

Source: [How to disable submit button parameter in Rails](http://lucastej.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-disable-submit-button-parameter.html).